# Excel - If cell A2 equals SKU then Clear cell C2,H2,G2 contents

Tags: excel, vba

Please help me format this VBA correctly:

```
Sub ClearColumns()
Dim lR As Long, Wrds As Variant, vA As Variant, R As Range, i As Long, j As Long
Dim R1 As Range, R2 As Range
lR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Wrds = Array("SKU")
Set R = Range("A1:A" & lR)
Set R1 = R.Offset(0, 2).Resize(1, 4)
Set R2 = R.Offset(0, 9).Resize(1, 4)
vA = R.Value
With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False
.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With
For i = LBound(vA, 1) To UBound(vA, 1)
For j = LBound(Wrds) To UBound(Wrds)
    If vA(i, 1) = Wrds(j) Then
        R1.Rows(i).ClearContents
        R2.Rows(i).ClearContents
        Exit For
    End If
Next j
Next i
With Application
.ScreenUpdating = True
.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With
End Sub
```

This is what I'm trying to do:

If cell in column A2 contains "SKU" Clear contents of D2, G2, H2, I2, J2, K2, L2, M2, P2, R2, AB2

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a method that does uses `Autofilter`, generally much faster than looping, and the `Range.SpecialCells` property, along with `Range.Offset` and `Range.Resize`:

```
Sub DeleteSkuRows()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim rngToClear As Excel.Range

Set ws = ActiveSheet 'change to suit
ws.Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="SKU"
Set rngToClear = ws.AutoFilter.Range.Rows(1).Offset(1)
Set rngToClear = rngToClear.Resize(ws.AutoFilter.Range.Rows.Count - 1, ws.AutoFilter.Range.Columns.Count)
Set rngToClear = Intersect(rngToClear, ws.Range("D:D,G:M,P:P,R:R,AB:AB")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
rngToClear.ClearContents
ws.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```